# how to write a INSERT INTO script in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to generate script using [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). But it is incorrect. I want to fix that code.

Here is the code:

```
 INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008].[HumanResources].[Department]
       ([Name]
       ,[GroupName]
       ,[ModifiedDate])
 VALUES
       (<Name, Name,>
       ,<GroupName, Name,>
       ,<ModifiedDate, datetime,>)
 GO
```

How to correct this code?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the issue you get?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Comment: Did you try to google how to create an insert statement prior to posting this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008].[HumanResources].[Department]
       ([Name]
       ,[GroupName]
       ,[ModifiedDate])
 VALUES
       ('Some Name'
       ,'Some Group Name'
       ,GetDate())
 GO
```

You have to fill in the values that are appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: You were 50 seconds quicker :)

Answer (score 0):

Your values list has to contain proper values:

```
INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008].[HumanResources].[Department]
       ([Name]
       ,[GroupName]
       ,[ModifiedDate])
 VALUES
       ('name',
       'groupdate'
       '20131106')
 GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

```
VALUES
   (Name,
   ,GroupName,
   ,ModifiedDate)
```

Also include values for the fields for example

```
INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008].[HumanResources].[Department]
   ([Name]
   ,[GroupName]
   ,[ModifiedDate])
VALUES
   ('User1',
   'Group1',
   getdate())

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong

**Sample Code :**

```
 INSERT INTO [AdventureWorks2008].[HumanResources].[Department]
           ([Name]
           ,[GroupName]
           ,[ModifiedDate])
     VALUES
           ('Name',
           'GroupName',
           GetDate())
     GO
```